# Python in SU cron gives different output than manually execution

Tags: python, sudo, cron

Ubuntu Server 9.10,
Here is my file, test.py

```
import commands
blkid = commands.getoutput('blkid')
print blkid
```

When I manually run (as SU) this:

```
python test.py
```

I get the output of the *blkid* as expected:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="3f0ac5bb-f0da-4574-81f5-77844530b561" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda5: UUID="67df0e7c-74fb-47dd-8520-ad720fbed67d" TYPE="swap"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="85466892-8dae-461c-95da-b8f91c2e766b" TYPE="ext3"
/dev/sdc1: UUID="91b84635-21c2-4d9a-84f8-2bbaab16d41f" SEC_TYPE="ext2" TYPE="ext3"
/dev/sdd1: UUID="6a52c830-0029-4154-80cb-f17274eb6fed" SEC_TYPE="ext2" TYPE="ext3"
```

However when I add this to my SU crontab:

```
* * * * * python /home/myusername/test.py > /home/myusername/output
```

The content of *output* becomes:

```
sh: blkid: not found
```

What am I missing here? Is the Python *commands* module only for certain SH-specific commands? I'm just try to run a system command and capture the output into a variable that I can parse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably with your `$PATH` versus root's (`os.environ['PATH']` if you're looking at it in Python rather than shell;-).  root's PATH is typically very conservative (it would be risky for it NOT to be!) and since you're running `blkid` without specifying an absolute path that may easily mean that it's on your PATH but not root's.

So do `which blkid` as yourself at a shell prompt, `sudo su` or anyway become root, and `echo $PATH` -- you can rapidly verify the problem.  Then you fix it by using blkid's absolute complete path in the `getoutput` call rather than just the bare identifier `blkid` as you're doing now.

Comment: That worked, thanks! I've always assumed the path when running a cronjob was the same as if you were actually typing in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

The environment (and PATH) of a cron job is not necessarily the same as your login shell.